# Can't Archive Ad-Hoc Distribution with Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, adhoc

I followed these two guides to create an .ipa file for Ad-Hoc distribution.

- http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4
- http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1237

For some reason the Project > Archive button is grayed out and the archive doesn't show up in Organizer.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you building it for simulator. You must select the option of device iPad/iPhone as you can not create .ipa for simulators.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your current build configiuration is "Simulator"? It needs to be device build to activate "Build and Archive"